# match() in an if statement is returning true instead of an array

Tags: regex, node.js, match

I copied this from another script (written by myself for the same purpose), so can't figure out why it isn't working as intended

```
} else if (new_var = message.toLowerCase().match(/!test\s(.+)/) && user === 'user') {
```

And then I am passing the following as `message`

```
!test test
```

So my understanding is that `new_var` should contain the following

```
new_var[0] = !test test
new_var[1] = test
```

However, `console.log(new_var)` is returning true

Comment: If you break up your expressions to single lines it will be easier to read, maintain, share, and lower the odds of bugs. https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/decompose-conditional

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning  the result of

```
message.toLowerCase().match(/!test\s(.+)/) && user === 'user'
```

to `new_var`, and `user === 'user'` presumably returns `true` in your case.

`&&` has a higher precedence than `=`. Use parenthesis to change it:

```
(new_var = message.toLowerCase().match(/!test\s(.+)/)) && user === 'user'
```

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I didn't have the && in my other script. Working fine now, thank you ver much :)